# It's possible include worker module in standard verticle?

Tags: worker, vert.x

Using vert.x in Java,
I would like use a worker module ( EBean ORM ) in a standard module(event loop) by declaring the "include" in mod.json or better setting the ebean module as system-module.

Will this block the event loop and so should i only use the eventbus instead?

Answer (score 0):

If your module has blocking code (using blocking APIs or doing a lot of computation), you should not use it on the event-loop. Golden rule: Never block the event-loop. Otherwise your application won't be responsive.

Even if the code in your module is non-blocking, I'd try to use the standard module way: You can reuse it with different languages much easier and if you decide to change internal implementation details in the future, you won't break your user-code as easy as you have the JSON interface via the event-bus.